# ios sdk Google map geocoding from a address to get exact latitude longitude

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-geocoder

I just want to find the location from an address entered in a textfield in Google Maps Application I have.

I am using the Google API for geocode but it returning array of results I just want to pick best matched result as google apps.

I am using [this](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600%20Amphitheatre%20Parkway,%20Mountain%20View,%20CA)

Comment: I have tried to make your question more clear to understand.

Comment: What do you mean by best?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you are getting is just one address with its different attributes. You can just parse  `"formatted_address" :` JSON object to get the human readable address.